# Create Java native code with Mono (AOT-Compiler)

Tags: java, mono

I found this: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/java/
And there it says:

> Compiling Java Code to x86 Code

So you could compile Java Code to an .exe, which could run on any windows machine without having anything to install?
I'm just wondering because the term "mono aot" did never occur while searching for compiling java native code.

So can I really make a native .exe from a .jar with this?
And which Java Version does it fully support?

Comment: It says you should run it with `mono Demo.exe`, which means you need Mono for it to work, thus you can't just dubbleclick, I suppose.

Comment: have you tried anything that is said in the page? whenever you test something, and it doesn't work as expected, please come back here with your question